# How to find the angle of a integer vector of coordinates -1, 0, +1

Tags: vectors, integers, angle

Is there a simple formula that would give me the angle of a 2D vector with integer coordinates in -1, 0, +1.
More precisely, I'm looking for the fastest way to calculate the following function:

(1,0) -> 0
(1,1) -> 1
(0,1) -> 2
(-1,1) -> 3
(-1,0) -> 4
(-1,-1) -> 5
(0,-1) -> 6
(1,-1) -> 7

Comment: How about `lookup_table[(x+1)*3+y+1]`?

Comment: Or even `(0123004765 >> (y*9+x*3+12)) & 7` (where `0123004765` is an octal constant)?

Comment: Or, slower but sticking to basic arithmetic, $2y^2-2y+2+x(2y^2-y-2)$.

Comment: @Troposphere thanks ! I’m interested to understand how you derived your formula. I was hoping for a something a bit simpler… after all, it’s just atan2(x,y)….

Comment: The polynomial one is just by noting that each of the _horizontal_ rows matches a linear function of $x$, then using Lagrange interpolation to write the slope and y-intercept as functions of $y$.